# Error C0000022 applying update operation 101708 of 138674 (\Regi...)

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

I am hoping to shed some light on an error I am getting.  This has been a long and involved problem, for which a case number already exists with Microsoft, however we seem to be getting nowhere.  I state at the outset that I believe it is one of the many updates being offered that for some reason will not run on my computer ... if I could figure out which one - I would simply avoid it.

My computer is a HP DV7-2022tx.  It is running Windows 8.1 Pro *and has been doing so since 2014*

Two weeks ago, I found my VPN unable to connect and in device manager noted that three of my WAN miniports were corrupt.  I bit the bullet and re-installed the system from scratch, removing the partition, then creating a new partition and formatting the disk.  I re-installed all my programs; and so began the problem of trying to install updates.  This is on a freshly installed system, you understand.

Anti-Virus is BitDefender (I removed AVG in favour of BitDefender) and PureVPN operates my VPN.  There are no other apps or programs likely to cause issues.

I contacted Microsoft First Level support, which merely resulted in a series of "refreshes", losing all programs and having to reinstall, whilst the problem persisted.  Eventually, (after much "lively discussion and encouragement") my case was handed off to Second Level support.  The tech dialed in and installed three "Hotfixes"

1. KB3102812
2. KB3173424
3. KB3172614

And started Windows Update.  184 updates were found and downloaded.  The computer installed, rebooted and failed.

I had learnt by this time to ensure that I created a System Restore point before allowing anyone on the computer, so I managed to restore.  By this time, it was the **FIFTH** refresh / restore I had done.  I was getting a mite tired of this.

The next day, Tech asked if I wanted to be upgraded to Win 10 after receiving report of error  ... I responded that if 8.1 Pro was failing, 10 wouldn't be much better would it.  He initially claimed that my computer wouldn't work with Win 8.1 according to HP website.  Was a bit stumped when I said that it had been running fine on 8.1 Pro from 2014 right up to last week (***funnily enough, just after "Patch Tuesday"*** .....) so he dialled in again and downloaded the very latest Win 8.1 Pro ISO using the media creation tool, reinstalled the three hotfixes (rebooted and worked fine) and downloaded the 184 updates again.  184 updates were found and downloaded.  The computer installed, rebooted and failed.  **SIXTH** system Restore performed by me.

Yesterday (7th June 2017) Tech dialled in, tried a further 3 MORE hotfixes :

4. KB3177108
5. KB3185331
6. KB3192392

184 updates were found and downloaded.  The computer installed, rebooted and failed.  **SEVENTH** system Restore performed by me.

I cannot continue to just allow a Tech to "try" something on my computer as it puts it out of commission for me for the day, plus the added headache of having to perform a "System Restore" at the end of the session is becoming nauseating.  **Clearly** there is an update that for whatever reason will not work with my computer.  Are there any savvy MVP's or Microsoft Specialists who can say that there is a known issue with download "n" on the architecture of a DV7-2022tx ?  Please?

UPDATE:  Further to suggestion offered, here is contents of poqexec.log:

1d2de7fb85252ae: 0, 0, 0, 0, StartTime ;
1d2de801e54fcc2: 0, 0, 0, 0, EndTime ;
1d2de9e23f28772: 0, 0, 0, 0, StartTime ;
1d2de9e302df892: 0, 0, 0, 0, CriticalPOQComplete ;
**1d2de9e23f28772: 8b4, c0000022, 1d242, 0, SetKeySecurity ;\Registry\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options**
1d2de9f37ba2f3e: 0, 0, 0, 0, EndTime ;
1d2de9f9c5761b3: 0, 0, 0, 0, StartTime ;
1d2dea0c2a99288: 0, 0, 0, 0, StartTime ;
1d2df3cd479d39a: 0, 0, 0, 0, StartTime ;
1d2df3cd80665e2: 0, 0, 0, 0, CriticalPOQComplete ;
1d2df3d1f9fea50: 0, 0, 0, 0, EndTime ;
1d2df571ef13e29: 0, 0, 0, 0, StartTime ;
1d2df57238eaae0: 0, 0, 0, 0, CriticalPOQComplete ;
**1d2df571ef13e29: 8b4, c0000022, 18d4b, 0, SetKeySecurity ;\Registry\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options**
1d2df5813bfadb6: 0, 0, 0, 0, EndTime ;
1d2df5883153bf0: 0, 0, 0, 0, StartTime ;
1d2df64af971a4e: 0, 0, 0, 0, StartTime ;
1d2df64b18992b7: 0, 0, 0, 0, CriticalPOQComplete ;
**1d2df64af94b5b8: 8b4, c0000022, d986, 0, SetKeySecurity ;\Registry\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options**
1d2df64d6345014: 0, 0, 0, 0, EndTime ;
1d2df651e09284d: 0, 0, 0, 0, StartTime ;
1d2df6557dae1e0: 0, 0, 0, 0, EndTime ;

Comment: 0xC0000022 = STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED - A process has requested access to an object, but has not been granted those access rights. Look in file "C:\Windows\WinSxS\poqexec.log" which operation failed with that error code

Comment: @magicandre1981 Many thanks for that - I have appended contents of poqexec.log in updated query.  I can see three such events - are you able to guide as to what it means ....?

Comment: ok, access to **HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options** is denied. Run regedit, go to that key and look if SYSTEM has full write permissions

Comment: @magicandre1981 That key has a large amount of subkeys (all .exe)
The **Image File Execution Options** itself has full permissions for SYSTEM to read / write.  
Possibly a subkey without correct permissions?  I wouldn't have thought so as they will all inherit parent permissions

Comment: do you use a AV software that may prevent access to this key?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I use BitDefender, as far as I am aware, that won't prevent access.  I'll check with BitDefender, but as it is consistently in the top 10 and right up there with kaspersky, I would be somewhat surpised if it was the cause ..... my partners HP thinbook is using it and it updates fine

Comment: remove the av suite and stop all 3rd party tools before trying to install the latest patches

Comment: @magicandre1981 - that's down for today.  I have removed BitDefender, and level 3 Microsoft Tech will be dialling into the computer shortly to run some more diagnostics ... will advise.

Comment: @magicandre1981 - looks like that cured it.  (although tech **did** run a chkdsk that went for 5 hours...) Went through with tech and installed updates 10 at a time.  All worked - including **2017-06 Windows 8.1 Security Monthly Quality Rollup** Which I note is the only one that has failed with a 0xc0000022 error on my Wife's HP laptop, running BitDefender.
So the question must be asked - what the hell is in this update that AntiVirus doesn't like?

Comment: I can't answer this. Ask this the bitdefender support. I only use NOD32 and never had issues

Comment: @magicandre1981 I'll do that - many thanks for advice though